# kylo ingest from file: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

[When i use kylo ingest from file,nifi flow failed and error happended,like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCfng.png)
[I guess it may happend in kylo meta service of the processor:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRvce.png)
[So i've tried to config the kylo application.prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2CKx.png)
Then I have tired to restart kylo & nifi,but the problem is going on.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately nobody is going to help you with your question in it's current format. You need to edit the question and put all the text of your errors into the question rather than externally link to images. Help people help you. Good luck, but for now I'm flagging as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check the Kylo Metadata Service controller service to verify that it is configured correctly. The settings in application.properties are only read the first time a controller service is created so that may be the issue you're running into.

To edit the controller service, go to the root flow in the NiFi UI then click the gear icon to configure the flow. Under the Controller Service tab you should see the Kylo Metadata Service controller service. You will need to disable it before you can edit once. Once you've verified the properties are fixed then enable the controller service and referencing components.